# Call a PHP file from Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, function, domdocument

Can I please have some help to call a PHP file via Javascript when an HTML page has successfully loaded.

Here is my code:

```
    <script class="code" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Call fb_marketing.php 
        });

    </script>
```

The name of the PHP file is 'fb_marketing.php'. Can I please have some help to get this code working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you need to do with the fb_marketing.php page ? that's the question

Comment: what should be the result of the "call"?

Comment: The fb_marketing.php page just needs to be loaded, just like browsing to it via a browser.

Comment: please read the FAQ of this site: a question is expected to show _what you've tried_, we should see that you've done your homework (as in: take a look what google has to say about AJAX), and the actual question should __NOT__ be _"write code for me"_, which you do seem to be asking here. SO is no free code generator, but a Q&A site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this file in AJAX as Musa said. Here is a sample code that tells what I mean:

```
    <script class="code" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div').load('fb_marketing.php');
    });

</script>
```

In this code, #div calls the place that you want to put your PHP file. You can use `this` instead of `'#div'`.

Comment: You should probably mention that this requires `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to watch the outcome you expect from php, one way to do is use JSON notation for a quick reading of the data. To this we must put the corresponding header in our php file which will return the result.